# Conjecture: The number of points modulo $p$ of certain elliptic curve is $p$ or $p+2$ for $p$ of form $p=27a^2+27a+7$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, finite-fields, conjectures

Numerical evidence suggests a conjecture that the number of
points of certain elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is
either $p$ or $p+2$ for $p$ of certain form.

Let $p$ be prime of the form $p=27a^2+27a+7$ and $(a/b)$ denote
the Kronecker symbol.

For integer $k$ nonzero modulo $p$ define $E_k / \mathbb{F}_p : y^2=x^3+2k^3$.

$E_k$ is the quadratic twist of $y^2=x^3+2$.

**Conjecture 1**: $\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)=p+1 + (2k^3 / p)$.

In other words for $p$ of the given form $\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is either
$p$ or $p+2$.

> Is Conjecture 1 true?

Example sage session with 200 bit $p$

```
sage: a=2^100+8;p=27*a^2+27*a+7;k=3;Kp=GF(p);E=EllipticCurve([Kp(0),Kp(2*k^3)])
sage: o=E.order();o2=p+1+kronecker(2*k^3,p);o==o2
True
```

Comment: We have $(2k^3/p) = (2k/p)$. Does  $(2k^3/p)$ suggest a generalization?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev probably this can be generalized by not using $2k^3$ but something else.

Comment: The quadratic twist by $k$ multiplies $a_p$ by $(k/p)$ so you may assume $k=1$ in your conjecture.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I know, but for cryptographic reasons I want the order to be $p$, so I need a twist.

Comment: The cryptographic point of this:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283767/conjecturally-unsafe-rsa-primes-p-27a227a7

Comment: The curve has CM by $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{1}]$, thus corresponds to some character. This conjecture, if true, can probably be proved easily. But I'm too lazy to work out the details...

Comment: @joro Sure, but for proving the conjecture you don't need $k$. I agree with WhatsUp. Here more hints of how to solve it (for $k=1$). Theorem 4 in Chapter 18 of Ireland-Rosen tells you what $a_p$ is when $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ in terms of sixth residue symbols. But since $4D=8$ is a cube this reduces to $(2/p)$. Then you need to factor $p$. I think $\pi = (9a+4-\omega)/(\omega-1)$ is a prime factor in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ with $\pi\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. Here $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$. Hopefully that helps proving the conjecture.

Comment: Generalization of this:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283853/primes-of-the-form-p-3a23abb2-or-p-27a227ab7b2-and-the-number-of-poi

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev possible generalization: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283853/primes-of-the-form-p-3a23abb2-or-p-27a227ab7b2-and-the-number-of-poi

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The conjecture is true. To prove it, we can restrict to $k=1$ as explained in the comments. Let $\chi$ denote a cubic Dirichlet character modulo $p$; this exists as $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, and it is unique up to complex conjugation. Let $\psi$ denote the (unique) quadratic Dirichlet character modulo $p$.

The number of points of the *affine* elliptic curve $E$ modulo $p$ equals
$$\sum_{y\bmod p}\left(1+\chi(y^2-2)+\overline{\chi}(y^2-2)\right)=p+\sum_{y\bmod p}\chi(y^2-2)+\overline{\sum_{y\bmod p}\chi(y^2-2)}.$$
The $y$-sum on the right hand side equals
$$\sum_{y\bmod p}\chi(y^2-2)=\sum_{z\bmod p}\chi(z-2)\bigl(1+\psi(z)\bigr)=\sum_{z\bmod p}\chi(z-2)\psi(z).$$
Here $\chi(z-2)=\chi(2-z)$, because $\chi(-1)=\chi((-1)^3)=\chi^3(-1)=1$. Therefore,
$$\sum_{y\bmod p}\chi(y^2-2)=\sum_{z\bmod p}\chi(2-z)\psi(z)=\chi(2)\psi(2)J(\chi,\psi),$$
where $J(\chi,\psi)$ is the corresponding [Jacobi sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_sum).

To evaluate the Jacobi sum $J(\chi,\psi)$, we rely on Chapter 6 of Rose: A course in number theory (2nd ed., Oxford University Press, 1994). By (the last part of) Exercise 10 at the end of this chapter,
$$J(\chi,\psi)=\chi(4)J(\chi,\chi).$$
Now we observe that $4p=1+27(2a+1)^2$, and this is the only way to write $4p$ as $u^2+27v^2$ with $u\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and $v$ positive, cf. Theorem 2.5 and the subsequent comments. Therefore, by Lemma 2.6,
$$J(\chi,\chi)=(3a+2)+(6a+3)e^{\pm 2\pi i/3}=\frac{1\pm(6a+3)i\sqrt{3}}{2},$$
the choice of the $\pm$ sign depending on which cubic character we denoted by $\chi$.

Putting everything together,
$$\sum_{y\bmod p}\chi(y^2-2)=\chi(2)\psi(2)J(\chi,\psi)=\chi(8)\psi(2)\frac{1\pm(6a+3)i\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
Here, $\chi(8)=\chi(2^3)=\chi^3(2)=1$, and so
$$\sum_{y\bmod p}\chi(y^2-2)+\overline{\sum_{y\bmod p}\chi(y^2-2)}=\psi(2)\sum_{\pm}\frac{1\pm(6a+3)i\sqrt{3}}{2}=\psi(2).$$

To summarize, the number of points of the *affine* elliptic curve $E$ modulo $p$ equals $p+\psi(2)$.

Comment: Generalization of this:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283853/primes-of-the-form-p-3a23abb2-or-p-27a227ab7b2-and-the-number-of-poi

Comment: Up to p=10^5 the only primes for which the order is p or p+2 are primes of this form. Did you prove this too?

Comment: @joro: No, I did not prove anything in the converse direction. You should formulate that as a separate question.

Comment: Have you seen similar elementary constructions of known order?

Comment: Asked new question about the other direction.

Comment: @joro: Your second conjecture is also true, I gave the proof below your other question.