# Primes of the form $p=3a^2+3ab+b^2$ or $p=27a^2+27ab+7b^2$ and the number of points of $y^2=x^3+2$ modulo $p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, finite-fields

Trying to generalize [this answered question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283758/conjecture-the-number-of-points-modulo-p-of-certain-elliptic-curve-is-p-or) based on limited numerical evidence.

Let $E / \mathbb{F}_p : y^2=x^3+2$.

**Conjecture 1** Let $p=3a^2+3ab_0+b_0^2$ be prime and $a,b_0$ 
positive integers.

Let $b=|p+1-\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$. For some integer $a$ (not necessarily positive)
$p=3a^2+3ab+b^2$.

In some non-rigorous sense if $p=3a^2+3ab+b^2$ then $b=|p+1-\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$.

**Conjecture 2** Let $p=27a^2+27ab+7b^2$ be prime and $a,b$ 
positive integers. Then $b=|p+1-\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$.
If the representation of $p$ in this form is not unique the conjecture 
is false (or possibly proceed as in Conjecture 1).

Example sage session:

```
sage: b=11;a=2^100+28;p=27*a^2+27*a*b+7*b^2;Kp=GF(p);E=EllipticCurve([Kp(0),Kp(2)])
sage: b2=abs(p+1-E.order());b==b2
True
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These conjectures are also true, and they follow similarly as in my proofs [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283758/conjecture-the-number-of-points-modulo-p-of-certain-elliptic-curve-is-p-or) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283862/e-mathbbf-p-in-p-p2-iff-p-is-of-the-form-27a227a7).

**Proof of Conjecture 1.** Let us denote $b=|p+1-\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$. The assumption on $p$ implies that $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, hence by my earlier posts, $4p=b^2+27c^2$ for some integer $c$. Then, $b$ and $c$ have the same parity, so that $3c=2a+b$ for some integer $a$. Finally,
$$4p=b^2+27b^2=b^2+3(2a+b)^2=4(3a^2+3ab+b^2),$$
and the conclusion $p=3a^2+3ab+b^2$ follows. Done.

**Proof of Conjecture 2.** The assumption on $p$ implies that $4p=b^2+27(2a+b)^2$, whence $b=|p+1-\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$ by my earlier posts. Done.

Comment: Do you still work with affine curves?

Comment: @joro: No, here I work with your notation. That is $\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ means the number of points of the projective elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.